# Linux shell script to sort lines of text reverse alphabetically (preferably without using sort)

Tags: linux, sh

I am trying to learn Linux shell scripting so am very new to this. I currently have a file (called alphabet.txt) that has 26 words, each starting with A-Z but they are not ordered here. For simplicity's sake, let's just make it 3 words, all on **different lines**, each word starting with A-C, such as the following: Banana, Apple, Carrot.

I want to know how to write a shell script that will take the contents of alphabet.txt, sort them in reverse alphabetic order and then place the sorted contents into a new file e.g. alphabetSorted.txt. So in the end, alphabetSorted.txt has to have the following: Apple, Banana, Carrot in order on different lines.

If possible I'd like to know how to make this work for any file and not just alphabet.txt.

Comment: it would be helpful to know why you have said in the title that you don't want a solution based on the `sort` command (which is the normal way to sort a file in a shell script)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
sort -r alphabate.txt -o sortedAlphabet.text
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sort command with '-r' flag, which specifies a reverse-order sorting.

Output can be redirect to a new file with

```
sort -r alphabet.txt > alphabetSorted.txt
```

or, using the built-in option -o, which allows the specification of an output file.

```
sort -r alphabet.txt -o alphabetSorted.txt
```

Both commands do exactly the same operation.